# Kendo window refresh not working for IE

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, refresh, kendo-dropdown, kendo-window

I am facing an issue with kendo window. It is not refreshing without debugging mode in IE 11. However the same refreshing mechanism is working if you press `F12` and ran the url. My Kendo version is "2015.1.318".

Back ground : at my project , we have kendo window feature. In that window , we have a drop down. The kendo window is opening trough a button click event. Kendo window should refresh every time before open, so that drop down value will update properly.

Actually , I saw that , this is working perfectly with other browser like chrome and Mozilla. Even it is working with IE in debugging mode. Even before button click to open the kendo window, if you clear the browser cache , then also it is working.

My project is only supporting IE, So I need to resolve it without `F12` work around or cache clear work around. I have used following technique to resolve.

`1) read : { cache: false } 
2) $("#window1).data("kendoWindow").refresh()`

But not working. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for contributing the answers.

The issue is resolved by using POST method. Earlier I was using $http.get. But I changed it to $http.post. Now refresh is working as expected.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onActivate` window event and manually reload all sources which you need, I think that even better solution because it will not recreate all DOM elements for your window

```
    var activate = function(){
        var dd= $("#dropDown").data("DropDownList");
        if(dd){
            dd.refresh();
        }
    }

    var win = $("#window1").data("kendoWindow");
    if (win) {
        win.title('window1');
        win.setOptions({
            width: '60%',
            modal: true,
            maxHeight: $(window).height() - 80,
            maxWidth: $(window).width(),
            deactivate: deactivate,
            activate: activate,
            actions: ["Close"]
        });
        win.center().open();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [correct syntax](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-refresh) is

```
$("#window1").data("kendoWindow").refresh({ cache: false });
```